# Node.js and API to save to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, node.js, api

I'm developing an API in PHP using the micro application feature from Phalcon Framework. This API consists in receiving GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests then return results from the MySQL database (the API has access to the database).

I'm developing a phonegap + ionic framework mobile application too and I need to connect all mobile users in realtime. Something like a chat, with informations returning from the API, for example: All profile informations like name, email, age, birthday will be stored and retrieved using the api.

My question is, its all possible to implement node.js here to make the app real time? Is there another way (using only ajax)? Ill need to create interactions between users, example: Someone will make a friend request to another user in real time, if the requested user accept the solicitation, it uses the api to update the mysql database, adding the user to the friendlist.

I want to use API because I dont want to give the future developers, the database access.